# If same value in two matrices, keep the value in the first matrix

Tags: matlab

how can I achieve the matrix C with following conditions:
A(i,j) is any B(k) , then A(i,j) = B(k)
else A(i,j) = 0

example:

A = [1 0 3 6 3 4; 2 0 3 1 8 2];
B = [1;2;3];

C = [1 0 3 0 3 0; 2 0 3 1 0 2]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A.*ismember(A,B)
```

Well not much to explain, ismember fits exactly your condition. Thus `ismember(A,B)` is 1 for all values you want to copy.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is to avoid products, you may try:

```
A(~ismember(A,B))=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you're looking for, from the matlab documentation

[LIA,LOCB] = ismember(A,B) also returns an array LOCB containing the
    highest absolute index in B for each element in A which is a member of 
    B and 0 if there is no such index.

```
 a = [9 9 8 8 7 7 7 6 6 6 5 5 4 4 2 1 1 1]
 b = [1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 9 9 9]

 [lia1,locb1] = ismember(a,b)
 % returns
 lia1 = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 locb1 = [16 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 13 13 0 3 3 3]
```

Comment: So d=[0,b];a=d(locb1+1) would statisfy what Fried Rice wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, without `ismember`:

```
A .* any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(B,[3 2 1])),3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys!

I followed your advise and extended the code for my task. I guess my question was unclear formulated:
Following your advice, the Matrix C will give only 1 or 0. 
I need the actual value of A in it.
In my following solution the code just rewrites A in the end. I gues there are many smarter solutions, but it works.

```
A = [1 0 3 6 3 4; 2 0 3 1 8 2]; 
B = [1;2;3];
[N M] = size (A);
C = ismember(A,B);


for i = 1:N
for j = 1:M
    if C(i,j) == 0;
        A(i,j) = 0;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: I think Daniel's solution does the same, at least it does for this example.

Comment: Nearly identical to my solution. `C=ismember(A,B);A=A.*C` is identical and faster.

Comment: did you notice the dot in the operator '.*' ?